# kernel 5.15.0-67 breaks monitor resolution after suspend

Tags: kernel, suspend, display-resolution

After installing kernel update 5.15.0-67 (in Ubuntu 22.04) mi laptop is unable to recognize after being suspended the highest possible resolution (2560x1440) of an external monitor connected through HDMI.
The resolution is OK when the computer starts fresh, but after suspending end resuming the session a lower resolution of (1920x1080) is detected. The maximum resolution is not available in Settings.

The problem is "solved" going back to the previous kernel (5.15.0-60), in which everything goes smooth, and the maximum resolution is detected after a long cycle of suspend-resume cycles.

The laptop is a Lenovo Thinkpad Carbon X1 and has Intel integrated graphics. 'lspci' outputs:
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation WhiskeyLake-U GT2 [UHD Graphics 620] (rev 02)

Comment: Report a kernel bug.

Comment: I also have an issue with the best graphics mode of my PC with Intel graphics after the same kernel update: [bug report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux-signed-hwe-5.15/+bug/2009672)

Comment: Similar issue with AMD graphics: https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/740695/111181